# Evenly spaced Tick marks for Primes

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, prime-numbers

I'm trying to have the integers evenly spaced on the x axis of a ListPlot, and the prime numbers evenly spaced on the y axis.

```
maxPrimeIndex = 25;
maxPrime = Prime[maxPrimeIndex];
Flatten[(Partition[
      Riffle[Flatten[FactorInteger[#]][[;; ;; 2]], #, {1, -2, 2}], 2]
     ) & /@ Range[2, maxPrime], 1];
ListPlot[%, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Prime[Range[1, maxPrimeIndex]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, maxPrime}, {0, maxPrime}}
 ]
```

Which gives: 
[image: Output of mathematica]

How can I get the y axis to be evenly spaced?

Comment: "prime numbers" and "evenly spaced" sounds like incompatible conditions. What exactly are you envisioning here?

Comment: Is it impossible to evenly space an arbitrary set? I'm just messing around; visualizing how many divisors there are around certain primes.

Comment: In the case of the primes, the spacing not being regular is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap).

Comment: If your points are *only* primes you can try adding `ScalingFunctions -> {PrimePi, Prime}` option to `ListPlot`.

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties But whether or not there are infinite spacings of 2 or 4 or 220 are unknown.

Comment: @kirma That worked. How do I accept your answer?

Comment: @Neil_P I'll make an answer from it first...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As people on the comments pointed out this may be a problematic in various ways, but if *all* y-values of your points are primes, this can be accomplished with `ScalingFunctions` option. `PrimePi` is an inverse of the `Prime` function, and you list both to guide `ListPlot`:

```
maxPrimeIndex = 25;
maxPrime = Prime[maxPrimeIndex];
Flatten[(Partition[
      Riffle[Flatten[FactorInteger[#]][[;; ;; 2]], #, {1, -2, 2}], 2]
     ) & /@ Range[2, maxPrime], 1];
ListPlot[%, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Prime[Range[1, maxPrimeIndex]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, maxPrime}, {0, maxPrime}},
 ScalingFunctions -> {PrimePi, Prime}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also map `PrimePi` on the second column of input data and change the vertical axis tick labels using custom ticks:

```
maxPrimeIndex = 25;
maxPrime = Prime[maxPrimeIndex];

data  = Flatten[
   Partition[Riffle[Flatten[FactorInteger[#]][[;; ;; 2]], #, {1, -2, 2}], 2] & /@ 
    Range[2, maxPrime], 1];

ListPlot[MapAt[PrimePi, data, {All, -1}], 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, 
   Thread[{Range @ maxPrimeIndex, Prime @ Range @ maxPrimeIndex}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, maxPrime}, {0, maxPrimeIndex}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this alternative came to my mind too. I wonder if there are cases where these solutions are not effectively identical. Certainly it's of pedagogical value to point out that tick labels don't need to correspond their actual coordinate values!